# WCF Client for web service with WS-Security, signed headers, authentication tokens and encryption of body

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, client, ws-security

I was assigned to create a client for a web service. I have no previous experience with web services and I have been trying with no success.
The web service is hosted at https://ws.conf.ebs.health.gov.on.ca:1441/EDTService/EDTService 
I was able to create the proxy classes with Visual Studio 2012 and create a basic client that was rejected by the service since it did not include any of the security specifications that the services require.
The following are extract from the documentation, that is available at http://www.health.gov.on.ca/en/pro/publications/ohip/default.aspx

The WS-Security section includes:
Technical specifications of the WSS 1.1
• Identity requirements;
• Signing requirements ;
• Encryption requirements; and
• Time stamps

IDP
To ensure confidentiality and integrity of sensitive information within the message, sender software must use public key technology to sign the SOAP headers and body.
The signing certificate can be any available certificate and can be self signed.
If any response data is specified to be encrypted, by the specific web service technical specification, the data will be encrypted using, at least, the AES128-CBC symmetric encryption algorithm with the public key belonging to the signer of the initial SOAP request. The encryption algorithm may be increased based on the specific web service technical specification.

My goal is to create a wcf client that can access this service. So far this is what I have done and it does not work:
This example tries to upload a file to the server:

```
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https://ws.conf.ebs.health.gov.on.ca:1441/EDTService/EDTService");
        //MCEDT userID and password
        string userId = "abcdefg";
        string password = "password";
        //MOH Id
        string mohId = "123456";
        //Vendor Conformance Key
        string key = "1234abcd-eeee-aaaa-ffff-abcdef123456";

public void upload()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Uploading....");
            //Specify the binding to be used for the client.
            WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);          

            binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
            UsernameToken ut = new UsernameToken(userId, password, PasswordOption.SendHashed);

            EDTDelegateClient client = new EDTDelegateClient(binding,address);            

            //Capture before send and after receive events
            client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new InspectorBehavior());            

            ebs_header EBS = new ebs_header();
            EBS.AuditId = "123456789";
            EBS.SoftwareConformanceKey = confomanceKey;

            //The MCEDT service will only support the IDP security model in its first release.
            idp_header IDP = new idp_header();
            IDP.ServiceUserMUID = mohId;

            msa_header MSA = new msa_header();
            MSA.UserID = userId;

            //data to upload
            //sample claim provided by OHIP
            uploadData data = new uploadData();
            data.description = claim_file;
            data.content = File.ReadAllBytes(@"..\..\" + claim_file);

            uploadRequest ur = new uploadRequest();
            ur.upload = new uploadData[1];
            ur.upload[0] = data;

            try
            {
                resourceResult result = client.upload(EBS, MSA, IDP, ur.upload);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
         }
    }
```

I  I believe that what I have done so far is in line with the technical requirements:
" The electronic system constructs a SOAP message using appropriate values and inserts the EBS and IDP headers into the SOAP message header with the user name and password (for the  IDP in a WS-Security Username token). The SOAP headers and body are then digitally signed to guarantee message integrity and source. If any request data is specified to be encrypted, by the specific web service technical specification, it will use the public key of the EBS system."
but I don't know how to sign the headers and body and how to encrypt the data. 
The certificates are provided with all the technical specifications and we have the proper information for user and password. It is only my lack of knowledge what is stopping to finish this project.
Thanks in advance to the community for the help.

Edit #1: Sample Message from Docs:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:msa="http://msa.ebs.health.ontario.ca/"
xmlns:idp="http://idp.ebs.health.ontario.ca/"
xmlns:edt="http://edt.health.ontario.ca/"
xmlns:ebs="http://ebs.health.ontario.ca/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ebs:EBS wsu:Id="id-4"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <SoftwareConformanceKey>444361ee-277f-7732-c684-7a9923jfgh1b</SoftwareConformanceKey>
      <AuditId>124355467675</AuditId>
    </ebs:EBS>
    <idp:IDP wsu:Id="id-3"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <ServiceUserMUID>1111222</ServiceUserMUID>
    </idp:IDP>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken
      EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"     
      ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"
      wsu:Id="X509-04FD51796CB607011413612828891871">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <ds:Signature Id="SIG-6" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ebs edt idp msa soapenv"
            xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
          <ds:Reference URI="#UsernameToken-2">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ebs edt idp msa soapenv"
                xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <ds:DigestValue>peTHpiEd5ujPqxNuKGN0k4p7up8c0dFPuRXbpQ+eMwI=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#TS-1">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse ebs edt idp msa soapenv"
                xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <ds:DigestValue>DqLqNQVHwzHRx7amwoYxEMwxN2g0/rND2I13WPP1Vhw=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-3">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ebs edt msa soapenv"
                xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <ds:DigestValue>K4IrndAA4zBmkumIfgKcluiKA8dmzwgGdKo5aq45LHg=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-4">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="edt idp msa soapenv"
                xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <ds:DigestValue>o92xRJQNwGz0Hv7DX87vSYUScX0qHL/bFGE3GmtUzQg=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-5">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ebs edt idp msa"
                xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <ds:DigestValue>svNyvvP+MrjIYlZFsg+bgw//8IPNVvIO9px3vYUfW3I=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
          qDSZlgY/aTFOzzo1C4tx+1E8ertrbmBySRxEK6sJ1JCt/77TLV5PBGnAme9Ttdmzf6h7/qb4rBGL 76LM0PaCQ9xm3DTsSQOz/So82G+/kX8M9TPY9D44+dvlB+cXm9rPn2BLMSVwtJf0kwI22SmRzMTR 6a6jfNYkGga6ZwZC9NLfG5/KTvsyZ39vOdO3T5GYc15RSjHKVBggoWmKm7x5PHrhU+3gClEbtHP8+Fgmmd9PJOtl9WunzR7NpY79xRNGxmDmL8hLvE4+uIc//b6TvrbGB2t8IWb5e5Wdz+ssHgMm0802 wFwGXlVxvSHpEJroHz5OvRgh7PKGlUSZP9fWkg==
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-04FD51796CB607011413612828892812">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-04FD51796CB607011413612828892813">
            <wsse:Reference
            URI="#X509-04FD51796CB607011413612828891871"
            ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2">
        <wsse:Username>johndoe@examplemail.com</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password
        Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">****</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-1">
        <wsu:Created>2013-02-19T14:08:08Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2013-02-19T14:08:38Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-5"
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <edt:upload>
      <upload>
        <content>
          <inc:Include href="cid:2341682853256" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" />
        </content>
        <description>00123</description>
        <resourceType>CL</resourceType>
      </upload>
    </edt:upload>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: get from the manuall a sample working soap request and publish here. then we can see how to configure WCF to send similar soap. free text about security requirements is usually more confusing.

Comment: I just added the example that comes with the documentation. Thanks for  fast your replay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: [See here](http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2013/12/consuming-ebs-edt-soap-service-from-wcf.html) a detailed solution to consume this EBS-EDT service

Since you have both username auth and x.509 signature you need to create the binding from code:

```
var sec = (AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement)SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10);
            sec.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new UserNameSecurityTokenParameters());
            sec.MessageSecurityVersion =
                MessageSecurityVersion.
                    WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10;
            sec.IncludeTimestamp = false;
            sec.MessageProtectionOrder = System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageProtectionOrder.EncryptBeforeSign;

            b.Elements.Add(sec);
            b.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8));
            b.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement());
```

Then you need to sign the headers. Assuming you use a message contract (not a data contract) where headers are explicitly tagged with a MessageHeader attribute then add to it a property "ProtectionMode=ProtectionMode.Sign".

Comment: I can't vote you up, cause I don't have enough reputation points. Since I am new to this web services technology, I still have a lot of questions, but I will try to use your answer as a starting point to do more research. One question. Is it b of type CustomBindings? Thanks

Comment: This is not the proper way to ask this, but is the only one I have nos. Did you receive an email I send you yesterday?

Comment: Could you resend it? I can't find it in my gmail account

Comment: what mail did you use? (I want to make sure I'm not resending someone else with a similar problem)